# Symfony3 UniqueEntity Validator ClassNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, validation, unique-constraint

I'm getting an error when using the `UniqueEntity` Symfony Validator.

> Attempted to load class "doctrine.orm.validator.unique" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

Here is my entity

```
<?php

namespace Isba\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Isba\CoreBundle\Entity\JsonResource;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Isba\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements JsonResource
```

Obviously I did the `use` statement and the class I'm refering to can be found in my project.

I'm using Symfony 3.3.6

**EDIT:**
Yes everything works perfectly without the validation (except that I've got an exception from my database because there is a unicity constraint at the DB level too).
Here is the result of the command

```
bin/console debug:container doctrine.orm.validator.unique

Information for Service "doctrine.orm.validator.unique"
=======================================================

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                                                  
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       doctrine.orm.validator.unique                                          
  Class            Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityValidator    
  Tags             validator.constraint_validator (alias: doctrine.orm.validator.unique)  
  Public           yes                                                                    
  Synthetic        no                                                                     
  Lazy             no                                                                     
  Shared           yes                                                                    
  Abstract         no                                                                     
  Autowired        no                                                                     
  Autoconfigured   no                                                                     
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And everything works as expected without the constraint?  Does "bin/console debug:container doctrine.orm.validator.unique" produce the expected output?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine. I added the result of the command in the description.

Comment: Normally a ClassNotFound is either an autoload issue or a typo.  That does not seem to be the case here.  I don't know why it thinks a service id is a class name.  You don't have any custom services or what not setup?  At this point, all I can suggest is either using a debugger or starting with a fresh project and adding your bundles back in.

Comment: Are you using any Annotation cache other than array? Maybe it hasn't flushed properly...

Comment: Even flushing the cache from the console (or rm the files) or removing all the vendors and reinstalling them didn't work.